# Return map of base classes from a derived class function

Tags: c++, dictionary, inheritance, return

I'm pretty rusty with my C++ and I need a bit of a refresher. I have an abstract class called `IReaderFactory` as follows:

```
class IReaderFactory
{
public:

    virtual std::map<t_ReaderID, IReader> GetReaders() = 0;
    virtual void FreeReaders() = 0;
};
```

I then have a derived class as follows:

```
class DerivedFactory : IReaderFactory
{
public:
    std::map<t_ReaderID, IReader> GetReaders();
    void FreeReaders();

private:
    std::map<t_ReaderID, DerivedReader> m_readers;
    LPDerived_DEVICE* devices;
    LPDerived_READER* readers;
    bool areReadersOpen = false;
};
```

And the implementation of the `GetReaders` function is as follows

```
std::map<t_ReaderID, IReader> DerivedFactory::GetReaders()
{
    int numDevices = 0, numReaders = 0;
    numDevices = Derived_DiscoverDevices(&devices);
    numReaders = Derived_DiscoverReaders(devices, numDevices, &readers);

    for (int i = 0; i < numReaders; ++i)
    {
        t_ReaderID ID = reinterpret_cast<char *>(readers[i]->id->id);

        DerivedReader o_Reader = DerivedReader(readers[i]);

        m_readers.insert(std::pair <t_ReaderID, DerivedReader>(ID, o_Reader));
        std::cout << ID << std::endl;
    }

    areReadersOpen = true;

    return m_readers;
}
```

Note that `DerivedReader` inherits from `IReader`

My compiler is issuing me the following error:
`IntelliSense: no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::map<t_ReaderID, DerivedReader, std::less<t_ReaderID>, std::allocator<std::pair<const t_ReaderID, DerivedReader>>>" to "std::map<t_ReaderID, IReader, std::less<t_ReaderID>, std::allocator<std::pair<const t_ReaderID, IReader>>>" exists`

I'd like to return my `DerivedReader` as an `IReader` within the `std::map`, but it will not allow me to do so. Any help would be appreciated.

---

**EDIT:**
Updated code to use `shared_ptr<IReader>` (Boost)

```
std::map<t_ReaderID, shared_ptr<IReader>> DerivedFactory::GetReaders()
{
    int numDevices = 0, numReaders = 0;
    numDevices = Derived_DiscoverDevices(&devices);
    numReaders = Derived_DiscoverReaders(devices, numDevices, &readers);

    for (int i = 0; i < numReaders; ++i)
    {
        t_ReaderID ID = reinterpret_cast<char *>(readers[i]->id->id);

        shared_ptr<DerivedReader> o_Reader(new DerivedReader(readers[i]));

        m_readers.insert(std::make_pair (ID, o_Reader));
        std::cout << ID << std::endl;
    }

    areReadersOpen = true;

    return m_readers;
}
```

Comment: You should have something like `std::map<t_ReaderID, IReader*>`

Comment: What is the type of `t_ReaderID`?

Comment: @NathanOliver Eerm, is that really relevant in 1st place if the map's value type is an abstract type?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ For his actual problem no but if it is some pointer type then that is also going to cause issue.  I just wanted to know in case it is.

Comment: @NathanOliver it's a std::string

Comment: @audiFanatic Well, as mentioned you cannot use an abstract type as `std::map::value_type` in 1st place. Use a pointer, or a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr<IReader>` as value type for the map.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That still doesn't seem to solve the issue. I'll post the updated code in a sec. I'm using Boost (not using C++11)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Got it, I forgot to change the definition of `m_readers`. So now it's `std::map<const t_ReaderID, shared_ptr<IReader>> m_readers` and I then made reader inheritance `public` as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472848/conversion-from-derived-to-base-exists-but-is-inaccessible

Comment: @audiFanatic Well, glad to push you into the right direction. It's absolutely OK you write an answer for your question, instead of editing the question itself.